# E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am struggling with this..please help me. I have attached logcat output too..please help me with this. i am calling database from localhost url as i have kept my database inside XAMPP mysql. The problem is that the ListView isn't showing anything at all. application is being crashed.

```
public class Delivery_info extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http:/127.0.0.1/hul/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "created_on";
private static final String TAG_DELIVERY = "delivery_id";
private static final String TAG_INVOICE = "invoice_amt";


// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delivery_info);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            /**Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Finances.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PRODUCTS, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);**/
        }
    });

}


// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Delivery_info.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PRODUCTS, id);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            }/** else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }**/
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * *
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Delivery_info.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_PRODUCTS,
                        TAG_DATE},
                        new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

```
    03-27 18:55:53.805  19554-19750/com.example.hul.hul E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
            at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.hul.hul.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:63)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Delivery_info.java:129)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Delivery_info.java:107)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-27 18:55:54.065  19554-19554/com.example.hul.hul E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4204c9d0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4204c9d0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:350)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(Delivery_info.java:119)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info.onCreate(Delivery_info.java:59)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 19:07:07.163  21510-21529/com.example.hul.hul E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
            at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.hul.hul.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:63)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Delivery_info.java:129)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Delivery_info.java:107)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-27 19:07:07.534  21510-21510/com.example.hul.hul E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4204d2c0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4204d2c0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:350)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(Delivery_info.java:119)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at com.example.hul.hul.Delivery_info.onCreate(Delivery_info.java:59)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you hit the URL from your browser/postman and check if it is giving proper response there?

Comment: yes ..it is giving proper response/...

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 issues here:

1- **127.0.0.1** should not be used on mobile, because it refers to the server
which is not the mobile itself. so change that IP to the actual IP address of the server or test machine (where xampp is installed)

2- you have a mistake in the URL itself (typo): missing **/** after http:

```
private static String url_all_products = "http:/127.0.0.1/hul/get_all_products.php";
```

should be

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/hul/get_all_products.php";
```

so your final url should look like (example):

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.10/hul/get_all_products.php";
```

or even a domain name:

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://my.api.domain/hul/get_all_products.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

if your service response is done in outside(PostMan) then you have to check in Java code means Internet Permission in manifest.